# Android Market-like tabbar

Tags: android, tabbar, android-tabhost

What's the best way to implement an Android Market-like tabbar (Apps/Games/Downloads)?

[image]

It would be great if I could use TabHost, but I believe it doesn't allow this level of customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cristian said, it's definitely possible using a `TabHost`, and you don't even need to use the androidtabs code that he links to. As of SDK level 4 (i.e. Android 1.6) you can pass a `View` to [`TabHost.TabSpec.setIndicator()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator(android.view.View)), which will allow you to completely control the look of the tabs.

However, tapping either of those buttons in the Market opens up a new Activity, and as such, using simple `Button`s might more closely reflect that behaviour than a TabHost would.

In the event that you need to support 1.5 as well, you could check out the zip archive from [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/55609a6413dad381). It contains TabHost etc. from Android 1.6. Copying this into your project should work, even on Android 1.5. You'll then have setIndicator(View v) available to you.

Comment: Thanks Kilnr. Unfortunately I have to target 1.5 devices too. I guess I can use the default style for 1.5 devices, and make use of setIndicator in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do using `TabHost`. Even better, you can find a fully functional example of how to do it here: http://code.google.com/p/androidtabs/

Answer (score 0):

Let try this code:

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
TextView txtTabInfo; // Reusable tab indicator

// Create our tab indicator
txtTabInfo = new TextView(this);
txtTabInfo.setText("videos");
txtTabInfo.setTextSize(16);
txtTabInfo.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
txtTabInfo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
txtTabInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.minitab);
txtTabInfo.setMinHeight(55);

spec = tabHostMM.newTabSpec("video");
spec.setContent(R.id.mm_video);
spec.setIndicator(txtTabInfo);
tabHostMM.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this job by changing the `tab.xml` file.
In `tab.xml` in linear layout, first use one child layout, which contains image and label(android market)
Below this child layout, put tab host and frame layout.
You can achieve this task then.