# Changing Tab Widget Border Color

Tags: android

I changed the background color of Tab WIdget in Android. But when I changed the background, I lost the border of each Tab.
I want to change the border color of Tab Widget. How can I change it? 
Is there any other way by which I can show the border?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255698/android-market-like-tabbar/3256051#3256051). If you need support for 1.5 it's a bit of a hack, but it'll work.