# Creating Android Market tab buttons

Tags: android

I am trying to mimic buttons (Apps, Games, Downloads) as seen in Android Market application

[image: play store image]

Checking the configuration of TabWidget, I think it's not possible to create this simple design with it. I decided to use simple buttons and try to create custom design following [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color). But still I cannot clone the design (gradient, divider, bottom line etc).

Are there any provided details how Google Android applications are built?

Comment: Most of the applications are opensource with the exception of the market, so your in tough luck there.

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255698/android-market-like-tabbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to customize the tabs in a `TabHost` by using the `setIndicator(View v)` method. You can recreate the gradient by defining it in xml and placing it in the drawable folder. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for some examples of defining drawables this way.

Answer (score 2):

The [API samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html) are usually your best bet with learning introductory Android concepts.  But as mentioned by Alxandr, Android Market is closed source.

However, I can tell you by looking at it that these are just three buttons, probably in a horizontal `LinearLayout`.  Each one has an `onClick` listener that starts a new `Activity`.  I can tell this because of the way they behave, and how when I click on one I am transitioned to a new screen.